# Group by parent but not by child

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, birt

Hi I am working with BIRT reports.
I have a query where I must group the repeated data of parent but the child must not be grouped too!

in my query:

[image]

item is the parent and item_ledger_entry is the child.
I have 3 repeated data from item.No and item.Description, and 3 non-repeated data from child. Now the output must be like this[image]
but since I am grouping it by No_ , the child is affected now and the current output is: [image]

My question is,
is there another way to group by No_ without affecting the Posting_Date??

If no, what could be the other way? Thanks!

Comment: Can I have some comments there? thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the group_concat to combine the posting_date to a string,then deal with it in the web or the program

Comment: Hi, I've already done this. It work well but my other codes got affected because of it.  Is there another way aside of group_concat?

Comment: I mean , as you can see in the image there's positive, neg,bal and entry type which varies from quantity. Since we are using concat, the value of quantity per No_ became 1 only. Not by 3 so the result of positve and others will be only 1 also.